# How can i remove empty space around my ICON when i using FLEXBOX in CSS?

Tags: html, css, inheritance, flexbox

I'm a beginner, can anyone explain how can i remove that Blue background color around my icon when i'm using flexbox?
i can't generalization my properties for children to their parent.
i haven't no global BG color.
i used FONTAWSOME.com website for icons.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQNkx.png)

```css
*{
    direction: ltr;
    background-color: #55efc4;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    font-size: 16px;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 150px 500px;
    
}
.title{
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;
    background-color: #00b894;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    text-align: center;
}
.user{
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    align-self: center;
}
#usericon{
    position: relative;
    align-self:auto; 
    padding: 0px; 
}
.userid{ 
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    align-self:auto;
}
#idname{
    position: relative;
    align-self: center;
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999 ;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
}
#idname:focus{
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00b894;
    -webkit-transition: 3s;
   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>login</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5dd6c7af4c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">LOGIN FORM</div>
            <div class="user">
                <form class="userid" action="">
                    <label id="usericon" for="idname"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" name="idname" id="idname">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

[my resault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e6y0.png)i don't want to using inline-flex. THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try adding `background-color: white` to `#usericon{}`.
If you have `*{background-color: "cyan"}` it makes all the elements backgrounds cyan, look in your css where you have that cyan color and find the cause.

Comment: i did but it didn't work, also i haven't *{background-color: "cyan"}

Comment: by cyan i mean the background color, not necessarily "cyan". the * selector adds the style to all elements, thats why i thought you might have it that sets the background color. i have no other idea why its behaving that way. you should edit the question and add the code as a codeblock not a screenshot